# How to set fact witch is visible on all hosts in Ansible role

Tags: ansible

I'm setting fact in a role:

```
- name: Check if manager already configured
  shell: >
    docker info | perl -ne 'print "$1" if /Swarm: (\w+)/'
  register: swarm_status

- name: Init cluster
  shell: >-
    docker swarm init
    --advertise-addr "{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}"
  when: "'active' not in swarm_status.stdout_lines"

- name: Get worker token
  shell: docker swarm join-token -q worker
  register: worker_token_result

- set_fact:
    worker_token: "{{ worker_token_result.stdout  }}"
```

Then I want to access worker_token on another hosts. Here's my main playbook, the fact is defined in the swarm-master role

```
- hosts: swarm_cluster
  become: yes
  roles:
    - docker

- hosts: swarm_cluster:&manager
  become: yes
  roles:
    - swarm-master

- hosts: swarm_cluster:&node
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ worker_token }}"
```

I'm getting undefined variable. How to make it visible globally?
Of course it works perfectly if I run debug on the same host.

Comment: if all is done in same playbook, you can access a fact of your manager from a worker using `hostvars[manager].worker_token`

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html 

Variables are set on a host-by-host basis just like facts discovered by the setup module.
These variables will be available to subsequent plays during an ansible-playbook run.
Set cacheable to yes to save variables across executions using a fact cache. Variables created with set_fact have different precedence depending on whether they are or are not cached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your goal is just to access `worker_token` from on another host, you can use `hostvars` variable and iterate through the group where you've defined your variable like this:

```
- hosts: swarm_cluster:&node
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ hostvars[item]['worker_token'] }}"
    with_items: "{{ groups['manager'] }}"
```

If your goal is to define the variable globally, you can add a step to define a variable on all hosts like this:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - set_fact:
      worker_token_global: "{{ hostvars[item]['worker_token'] }}"
    with_items: "{{ groups['manager'] }}"

- hosts: swarm_cluster:&node
  tasks:
  - debug:
      var: worker_token_global
```

Comment: OMG. It took me one day until I understood, but it works. Thanks. :)

Comment: if hosts are members of group "all" could you set a variable for the "all" group to allow all group members to see it?

Comment: @majorgear yes, it is the purpose of the step set_fact of `worker_token_global` in my example .

Comment: I discovered that if set localhost hvars with a play where hosts was localhost, and then ran another play where hosts did not include localhost (i.e. hosts: notlocalhost ), the localhost variable was not available. For my case, I set the localhost hostvars by delegating the tasks to localhost , and setting run_once to true so it only ran once. They were accessible by other hosts that way.  Complicated, but works!